# Display button only on signup not on signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise gem for user authentication with confirmable (Email confirmation).
I want to display a tour button on home page only after user signup but not on login. Iam doing something like this

```
    <% if current_user && current_user.confirmed_at_changed? && session[:tour].blank? %>
   <% session[:tour] = true %>
    <div id="outsider">
      <button id="startTourBtn" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Take a tour</button>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

But this is not working.....
Thanks in advance for any suggestion, advise.

Comment: you can check if the created_at in your User table is same as Date.today(current_user.created_at == Date.today), than the button is only visible for new users.

Comment: current_user.created_at.to_date == Date.today works only fine but what if the user logs out and signin again on the same day. Then in this case it will not work,Because the user logs in on the same day.

Comment: ... current_user.created_at.to_time == Time.now :ugly:

Comment: ah, the answer from Sumit Rai with current_user.sign_in_count is clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally  found it thanks to devise I can use the sign_in_count to display the button only for signed up users
and not for logged in users by checking (current_user.sign_in_count == 1).And it will shown only once :)

```
  <% if current_user && !current_user.sign_in_count.blank? && current_user.sign_in_count == 1 && session[:tour].blank? %>
    <% session[:tour] = true %>
    <div id="outsider">
      <button id="startTourBtn" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Take a tour</button>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your users cannot sign in with not confirmed emails then you could just check if `current_user` present or use `user_signed_in?` devise's helper method.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers